# Im confused on how to print out my fav food is cake on my console and I also keep getting an error that says 'Person' object has no attribute 'Food'

Tags: python

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self,Food):
    
    def FindFood(self):
      print("my fav food is"+ self.Food)
p1 = Person("cake")
p1.FindFood()
```

Comment: class Person:
  def __init__(self,Food):
    
    
    

    def FindFood(self):
      print("my name is "+ self.Food)
p1 = Person("cake")
p1.FindFood()'

Comment: Edit the question to show code, don't use comments.

Comment: Can you please edit your post so that the code you have written is clear and easy to read?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: There is no code under `__init__`.  Needs `self.Food = Food` to store the value passed in as an attribute.  Also fix the indentation for `FindFood`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some code, and your indentation is off. First, in your class's `__init__` method, you need to assign the `Food` argument to the attribute `self.Food`. It doesn't happen automatically.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,Food):
        self.Food = Food
```

Next, your method `FindFood` is a sibling to the `__init__` method, not contained within it, so you need to unindent it one level.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,Food):
        self.Food = Food

    def FindFood(self)
        print("my fav food is "+ self.Food)
```

The rest of your code is correct: make an instance of your class called `p1`, passing the `Food` argument `"cake"`. Then, call the `FindFood` method and it prints the result.

Note that I changed the indentation to 4 spaces, as specified in [PEP 8 -- The Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).